# Javascript - Prototyping on DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I'm building custom libraries to handle GUI and creating divs and stuff programatically. I also want to extend these objects with children and methods to do something like this:

```
Function CustomElement() {
  this = document.createElement('div');
  ///--------
  Some custom properties
  ///--------
}

CustomElement.prototype.customMethod = function(args) {
  ///--------
  Some code here
  ///--------
};

var elem = new CustomElement();

document.body.appendChild(elem);

elem.customMethod(args);
```

I've thoroughly searched for an answer but found none. How can I accomplish this?

Note: I'm posting from my cell phone. Please excuse me if the code looks awful. I'll correct it as soon as I have access to a PC.

Comment: Are you running into a problem trying to implement this? Does this need to be your own custom library? Maybe an existing solution like React would suit your needs better?

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: You cannot assign to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears you are confused between **classical** languages such that you are probably use to, and **prototypical** like languages such as Javascript.

Also, in your example, assigning the value of `this` is an invalid statement.

In Javascript, instead of creating children of a super class, we create objects that inherit the properties of other objects through the **prototype chain**. Still with me? This means that your `customMethod` is not technically a method, rather it is a property called `customMethod` which has the value of a function object.

Every *constructor* object (which is just a fancy name for your `CustomElement` function) has a magical property named `prototype` as you have discovered. Objects don't have this property, but they do have an implicit reference to their constructor's prototype object. This means you can call your `customMethod` as if it were a property of `elem`, but it is really a property of the constructors prototype object. So I guess you could say the prototype object is kind of like a parent and the object is kind of like a child (although this is incorrect terminology). This prototype object may also again have an implicit reference to it's constructor prototype, which may reference it's constructor prototype... and so on. That's why its called the **prototype chain**.

### So to answer your question:

> I also want to extend these objects with children and methods... How can I accomplish this?

For a suggestion to emulate child like inheritance, see below. However, your library requires a different approach...

A common angle of attack is to create a constructor which creates a new object, with a new Element object as a property of that object. For example:

```
function CustomElement(doesLikeTrains) {
    // keep element in this property
    this.nativeElement = document.createElement('div');

    // other properties are separate
    this.likesTrains = doesLikeTrains;
}

// these are also separate 
CustomElement.prototype.doesLikeTrains = function() {
        return this.likesTrains;
};

// Lets make objects!
var elem1 = new CustomElement(true);
var elem2 = new CustomElement(false);

// use object property and inherited properties
// we can still use the element ok
document.body.appendChild(elem2.nativeElement);
elem1.doesLikeTrains(); // prints true
elem2.doesLikeTrains(); // prints false :(
```

The DOM element assigned to the `nativeElement` property. This means you may add other properties without changing the native element object, but still have access to them. Both `elem1` and `elem2` inherit the same `doesLikeTrains` property with the same value, but each have their own `likesTrains` property, which is initialised in the constructor, and can keep a value specific to the object instance.

The advantage of this is that you could change the `doesLikeTrains` function to always return true, and because all objects created using your `CustomELement` constructor inherit the same prototype, all objects would then like trains regardless!

### How would one create children like objects?

To emulate a child structure, consider...

```
function CustomOtherElement(likesTrains, runsOnCoal) {

    // create new object and inherit from CustomElement
    function EmptyConstructor() {}
    EmptyConstructor.prototype = new CustomElement(likesTrains);

    // add extra stuff to CustomOtherElements only
    EmptyConstructor.runsOnCoal = runsOnCoal;
    EmptyConstructor.isTrainSuperFan = function () {
        return "Hoot hoot, chugga chugga!";
    }

    // return the new object
    return new EmptyConstructor();
}

// now you can do
var elem3 = CustomOtherElement(true, true);
document.body.appendChild(elem3.nativeElement);
elem3.doesLikeTrains(); // true
elem3.isTrainSuperFan(); // "Hoot hoot, chugga chug!"
```

The above uses this new `CustomOtherElement` constructor to make an object that inherits `CustomeElement` and then add some new properties to this new object. Now you can use both the inherited properties from `CustomElement` and the new ones created on `elem3`! Happy Javascripting!

Resource: ECMAScript Language Specifications 5.1 section 4.2.1 (Objects)

Comment: Both answers were great, but I ended using this approach after reading http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Answer (score 1):

Consider the approach sometimes called "parasitical inheritance". In this pattern, you write a constructor function, but return something else after adding methods/properties to it, such as

```
function CustomElement() {
  var elt = document.createElement('div');

  ///--------
  Some custom properties
  ///--------

  elt.customMethod = function(args) {
    ///--------
    Some code here
    ///--------
  };

  return elt;
}

var myCustomElement = new CustomElement();
```

This can be simpler, and more reliable, than trying to subclass `HTMLElement`, which can be a delicate operation, or wrapping the underlying HTML element, as other answers suggest.

Some might complain that the above approach is fat or slow because the "prototype" methods are being placed on each instance. However, that's something that's not really an issue on modern machines and browsers.

In any case, once we've come this far, we need to ask why we are trying to use constructors and `new` at all, when we can simply say:

```
function makeCustomElement() {
  var elt = ...;
  // set custom properties
  // set custom methods
  return elt;
}

var myCustomElement = makeCustomElement();
```

Defining a "subclass" is as simple as:

```
function makeCustomElementSubclass() {
  var elt = makeCustomElement();
  // set custom properties and methods
  return elt;
}
```

In none of the cases above are prototypes being used (except methods on the built-in prototype such as `HTMLElement`). They're not really necessary. As I understand it, this is the direction in which mega-guru Douglas Crockford has gravitated in his style. Many cases where we see people using prototypes, it is a matter of "let me figure out a way to do this using prototypes, because they exist and I sort of think I'm supposed to be using them", or "let me figure out a way to do this using prototypes because they sort of behave like the classes I'm used to from C++/Java/C#", or "let me use prototypes to do this because putting methods once on prototypes is so much more efficient than putting them on each object"--but none of these are compelling reasons.